# Can and/or should I declare meta charset utf8mb4

Tags: html, utf-8, utf8mb4

I'm planning on using utf8mb4 in my database.

Now as I've learned I should always use UTF-8 in my `<meta charset`, but do I always do, so when I'm using utf8mb4 in my database?

Comment: What do you mean by "meta"?

Comment: @RickJames In HTML you declare for example <meta charset="UTF-8"> in de head tag.

Comment: Why does the database matter? Your HTML page isn't querying the database; you'd hit some API which would return its own character encoding.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

utf8mb4 is specific to MySQL. The rest of the world calls it UTF-8.

Comment: So, to clarify, in HTML the utf-8 character set is exactly the same as utf8mb4? In MySQL utf-8 is the equivalent of utf8mb3 which does not support all of the unicode characters. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html